# How to get last log from all partition in ConsumerGroup

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to get last log from all partition in consumerGroup, in one consumerGroup may be partition from different topic.

I don't log to groupID so i couldn't use `consumer.subscribe(sth topic)`

```
@PostConstruct
public void connectionKafkaConsumer(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "xyz");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
}  


public void getLog(List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions) {
    consumer.assign(topicPartitions);

    for (TopicPartition topicPartition : topicPartitions) {
        long endPosition = consumer.position(topicPartition);
        long recentMessagesStartPosition = endPosition - 1;
        if (recentMessagesStartPosition < 0) {
            System.out.println("None message.");
            return;
        }

        consumer.seek(topicPartition, recentMessagesStartPosition);
        ConsumerRecords records;
        try {
            records = consumer.poll(2000);
        } catch (SerializationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        Iterator iter = records.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ConsumerRecord consumerRecord = (ConsumerRecord) iter.next();
            System.out.println(consumerRecord.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of last log from all partition, but the actual output is

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: 
Error deserializing key/value for partition my_partition at offset 16634750. 
If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
```

The line giving the exception is `records = consumer.poll(2000);`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG should be String in some my kafka topić/particion. I haven't notice this before that key is sometimes String.